# Android, Realm: Is need every time call realm.insert(permissionOfferResponse)?

Tags: android, realm

On Android client I need to get realmURL. So I do the next steps:

1. Login to Realm Object Server (ROS)
2. Create response with received token
3. After processing, offerResponse's realmUrl property will contain the URL of the shared Realm

Here snippet:

```
public class MainApp extends MultiDexApplication {

 private void loginAndConfig() {
        String authUrl = "http://" + BuildConfig.OBJECT_SERVER_IP + ":" + BuildConfig.OBJECT_SERVER_PORT + "/auth";
        SyncUser.Callback callback = new SyncUser.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SyncUser user) {
                setPermissions(user);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(ObjectServerError error) {
                String errorMsg;
                switch (error.getErrorCode()) {
                    case UNKNOWN_ACCOUNT:
                        errorMsg = "Account does not exists.";
                        break;
                    case INVALID_CREDENTIALS:
                        errorMsg = "User name and password does not match";
                        break;
                    default:
                        errorMsg = error.toString();
                }
                Log.w(TAG, "loginAndConfig: onError: result errorMsg = " + errorMsg);
            }
        };

        SyncCredentials syncCredentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(
                BuildConfig.USER_NAME, BuildConfig.PASSWORD, false);
        SyncUser.loginAsync(syncCredentials, authUrl, callback);
    }

    private void setPermissions(final SyncUser syncUser) {
        Realm managementRealm = syncUser.getManagementRealm();

        // Create response with received token
        String offerToken = BuildConfig.REALM_OFFER_TOKEN;
        final PermissionOfferResponse permissionOfferResponse = new PermissionOfferResponse(offerToken);

        // Add to management Realm to sync with ROS
        managementRealm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
            // call every time on start 
                realm.insert(permissionOfferResponse);
            }
        });

        // After processing, offerResponse's realmUrl property will contain the URL of the shared Realm
        // Wait for server to handle the offer
        RealmResults<PermissionOfferResponse> realmResultPermissionOfferResponse = managementRealm.where(PermissionOfferResponse.class)
                .equalTo("statusCode", 0)
                .findAll();
        realmResultPermissionOfferResponse.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<PermissionOfferResponse>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(RealmResults<PermissionOfferResponse> offers) {
                PermissionOfferResponse offer = offers.first();
                String realmURL = offer.getRealmUrl();
                // success get relmURL
            }
        });
}
}
```

As you can see this code start on every start of application. AS result it every time call method **realm.insert(permissionOfferResponse)**.

Question: Is I need to call method **realm.insert(permissionOfferResponse)** EVERY TIME when start application?

Comment: No, you should only create the offer response once

Comment: So how I can undestand that method `realm.insert()` already called once?

Comment: 1. Check from **SharedPreferences** is _relmUrl_ already exist. 2.1 If not then call **block of method to get realmURL from ROS**.   2.2. If exist _relmUrl_then miss **block of method to get _relmUrl_from ROS**.   3. Set realmURL to SharedPreferences. Is this a good solution?

Comment: Yes, that will work fine.